# Python 3, telnet automation

Tags: python, automation, telnet, switching

Im doing a project which is to collect certain information from a number of switches. Keep in mind im new to python and programming.
What i want to do, is to: have a .txt file with the names of my switches.
Then loop through that list, and run a few commands, and save the output.

So far i have the following, which works on a single switch. As you can see in the comments, im trying to open my list.txt and loop through it, but my program wont work due to it being in a list (output: ['switchname-1'] ) How do i read my list.txt and get the variable as plain text, eg. switchname-1 without all the list chars ?

```
import sys
import telnetlib
import time

password = "password"
command = "show interface status"

##with open ("list.txt", "r") as devicelist:
##    hostlist = []
##    hostlist=devicelist.readlines()
##    print(hostlist)
hostlist= [ ("switchname-1","",""),]

for host in hostlist:

        cmd1 = "enable"
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host[0])

        time.sleep(2)
        tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
        tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        tn.write(cmd1.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        tn.write(command.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        tn.write(b"\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        tn.write(b"\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        tn.write(b"exit\n")
        lastpost = tn.read_all().decode('ascii')
        op=open ("output.txt", "w")
        op.write(lastpost)  
        print("writing to file")
        op.close()
        print(lastpost)
        tn.close()
```

I am also trying to figure out if there is some kind of way to only print the last output from the switches instead of `lastpost = tn.read_all().decode('ascii')` which posts the whole telnet session ?

Comment: does tn return \n delimited text?  if so use tn.split("\n")[-1] to get last line.  Sorry, I missed that part in my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
with open ("list.txt", "r") as devicelist:
  hostlist = []
  hostlist=devicelist.readlines()
  for host in hostlist:
    print host
  print(hostlist)
```

But I think it would be better to write as function:

```
def host_list(file_name):
  with open(file_name, "r") as devicelist:
      yield devicelist.readline()
```

Then in your code below do:

```
  for h in host_list("your_file"):
     ...
```

The function will read the file a line at a time and return (yield) the text.

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
import sys
import telnetlib
import time

password = "pw"
command = "sh ver"
term = "term len 0"

data = open("hostlist.txt")
for line in data:
    cmd1 = "enable"
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(line.rstrip())
    tn.set_debuglevel(1)
    time.sleep(2)
    tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
    tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    tn.write(cmd1.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    tn.write(term.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    tn.write(command.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    tn.write(b"\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    tn.write(b"\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    tn.write(b"exit\n")
    lastpost = tn.read_all().decode('ascii')
    print(lastpost)
    op=open ("output.txt", "a").write(lastpost)
    tn.close()
```

Comment: Does your lastpost do what you need?